# LocalStorage not updated during alert-block

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage, google-chrome-devtools

Today I struggled with a weird behavior with local storage, that I broke down to a simple scenario. It seems that the Chrome Browser does not sync the `localStorage` if an alert box is during the value is written.

There are 2 browser tabs opened.

Tab *A* requests the file *read.html*:

```js
    var item = localStorage.getItem('test');
    console.log('item before alert', item);

    alert('Pause!'); // don't close it before calling write.html

    item = localStorage.getItem('test');
    console.log('item after alert', item);
```

The alert box saying "Pause!" will not be closed.

Another Tab *B* is requesting the file *write.html*:

```js
    var item = (localStorage.getItem('test') || '') + 'a';
    console.log('new item:', item);
    localStorage.setItem('test', item);
```

You can see that the value was updated in the localStorage in the browsers (Chrome) Devtools, but only in the one of Tab *B*.

This only happens in Chrome. IE11 and Firefox are working as expected. Does anyone have a clue if this is by design or a bug in Chrome?

Regards
Markus

Edit: Created a github project with the code: https://github.com/wondee/localStorage-bug

Update: After Artyoms answer I tried to wait for the dispatching, and it really helped with the following code added in *read.html* after the last `console.log(..)` the changes are reflected correctly:

```
setTimeout(() => console.log('item after 1s:', localStorage.getItem('test')), 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#the-localstorage-attribute) (read it till the end to cover possible questions).

> When the setItem(), removeItem(), and clear() methods are called on a Storage object x that is associated with a local storage area, if the methods did not throw an exception or "do nothing" as defined above, then for every Document object whose relevant global object's localStorage attribute's Storage object is associated with the same storage area, other than x, **send a storage notification**.

Basically, as far as I understand it, when user opens new tab with the same origin, **copy of storage is created**. So when storage is modified in one tab - a storage event is sent (**task is queued**) to all the other tabs (for the same origin) to synchronize them.

> When a user agent is to send a storage notification for a Document, the user agent must queue a task to fire an event named storage at the Document object's relevant global object, using StorageEvent.

But in your particular case, because of synchronous `alert()`, event loop can't pick up this queued storage event until your script is finished and call stack is empty.

But as soon as your script in the first tab is finished, event loop will pick this event up and reflect the changes on its storage copy.

But there is a clear warning in the spec, that you should avoid updating the same shared state the way how you do it in your example, since there is no locking mechanism.

> Warning! The localStorage attribute provides access to shared state. This specification does not define the interaction with other browsing contexts in a multiprocess user agent, and authors are encouraged to assume that there is no locking mechanism. A site could, for instance, try to read the value of a key, increment its value, then write it back out, using the new value as a unique identifier for the session; if the site does this twice in two different browser windows at the same time, it might end up using the same "unique" identifier for both sessions, with potentially disastrous effects.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing localStorage before setting the new value? try

```
localStorage.removeItem('test');
localStorage.setItem('test',item);
```

Comment: I do not want to remove it. I just want to change it.

Comment: Actually changing or updating means removing the old value and inserting a new one.
This operation is supposedly done automatically by the browser, but since it is not maybe try doing it manually. Just test it.